# Python: how to launch scp with pexpect without OpenSSH GUI Password Prompt on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, pexpect

I'm attempting to automate `scp` commands with `pexpect` on Ubuntu. However, I keep getting a password GUI prompt with title "OpenSSH". How can I disable this behavior and use command line prompts instead?

Comment: While it may be interesting to fine-tune scp, why don't you just use passwordless logins(with public/private keys) instead?

Comment: pbhihag's answer will work. You also might consider using Paramiko, a native SSH client for python: http://www.lag.net/paramiko/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `DISPLAY and SSH_ASKPASS` section of `man ssh-add`.